# Как перенести историю скайпа из Windows в Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, skype

В Windows (у меня Windows 7) Скайп хранит историю в файле `main.db`. Что сделать с этим файлом, чтобы история стала доступна в Linux Mint?

Comment: А если запустить параллельно виндушный и линуксовский клиент, он через центральный сервер не перегонит историю?

Comment: Запущеный в 3 экземплярах (на двух линуксах и андроиде одновременно) перегоняет историю моментально. Но вот что с синхронизацией статусов и других мелочей... Какая-то копия является "ведущей", но какая именно - так и не разобрался.

Comment: [SkypeExport](https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport) утверждает, что видит даже те сообщения, которые официальный клиент не видит. На Windows можно готовые бинарники взять и передать путь к main.db, чтобы историю ввиде html произвести. А недавняя история и так доступна должна быть, например, если первый раз зайти на https://web.skype.com/ то история всё равно показывается.

Comment: @VladD, автоматическая синхронизация работает только за последний месяц или два. Да и то как-то криво...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная база скайпа находится здесь: `~/.Skype/имя_аккаунта/main.db`. Соответственно, либо переносить этот файл целиком, либо объединять таблицы `Messages`.

Во всяком случае такое проходит: основная система - минт, ставим скайп под виндой, переносим туда линуксовый `main.db`, и всё подхватывается без проблем.

Comment: Т. е. файл базы платформонезависимый? Хотя да, логично.

Comment: Так это просто база sqlite.

Comment: А ещё можно не переносить, а просто сделать симлинк в линуксе. Т.е. храним сам файл на виндовом разделе, а в линуксе это будет просто симлинк с абсолютным путём.